# How to get \vsplit to separate an equation from the previous line

Tags: page-breaking

I've been experimenting with determining the height of lines by using `\vsplit` to break up a paragraph.  I've set pretty much every penalty associated with page breaking to 0.  It's not the end of the world if it can't be split off, but I'd like to know why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{count}
\newlength{\size}
\newlength{\total}
\newlength{\prev}

\begin{document}

\setbox0=\vbox{This is the first line of a paragraph, so there is a penalty for
splitting here.  This is the line before a display, so ditto.
\begin{equation}
x=a
\end{equation}
Everything should return to normal now.}

\noindent\usebox0

\bigskip
\total=\ht0
\advance\total by \dp0
total height = \the\total

\clubpenalty=0
\widowpenalty=0
\displaywidowpenalty=0
\predisplaypenalty=0
\postdisplaypenalty=0
\interlinepenalty=0

\total=0pt
\loop\prev=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0\relax
  \setbox1=\vsplit0 to \baselineskip
  \stepcounter{count}%
  \size=\dimexpr \prev-\ht0-\dp0\relax
  \advance\total by \size
  \thecount{ = }\the\size\par 
  \ifdim\ht0>0pt\repeat

total height = \the\total

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to set the penalties *before* building the box

Comment: `\noindent\begin{document]` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -Oops, partial edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

the penalties are part of the box structure, so changes after the box is set have no effect, setting them earlier produces four lines rather than 3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{count}
\newlength{\size}
\newlength{\total}
\newlength{\prev}

\begin{document}


\clubpenalty=0
\widowpenalty=0
\displaywidowpenalty=0
\predisplaypenalty=0
\postdisplaypenalty=0
\interlinepenalty=0

\setbox0=\vbox{This is the first line of a paragraph, so there is a penalty for
splitting here.  This is the line before a display, so ditto.
\begin{equation}
x=a
\end{equation}
Everything should return to normal now.}

\usebox0

\bigskip
\total=\ht0
\advance\total by \dp0
total height = \the\total

\total=0pt
\loop\prev=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0\relax
  \setbox1=\vsplit0 to \baselineskip
  \stepcounter{count}%
  \size=\dimexpr \prev-\ht0-\dp0\relax
  \advance\total by \size
  \thecount{ = }\the\size\par 
  \ifdim\ht0>0pt\repeat

total height = \the\total

\end{document}
```