# Marking line wraps

Tags: line-breaking

I have the following MWE to typeset two text paragraphs with the first line outdented.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\parindent=-1em
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

How do I mark line wraps with a `↳` (or similar) character?

Similar behaviour is found in listings or minted.

Is there something like `\everypar` for lines (except the first line of the paragraph)?

Comment: You could expand the paragraph in a \vbox and use \vsplit to create your own line breaks, but the boxes would include the indentation space.  The lineno package works by setting \interlinepenalty=-100000 and replacing \output.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you. `lineno` looks like something which has similar functionality, with some hacks it can probably be made to work as I need. I'm not sure what you mean with vbox and vsplit, could you perhaps give me an example?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295039/how-to-get-vsplit-to-separate-an-equation-from-the-previous-line?s=1|1.2962