# How to write text in LaTeX with "mixture of 3 colours"

Tags: color

I need help to write text in LaTeX - a mixture of 3 colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    
%% Single-color
\textcolor{blue}{I used Single color for this text}

 %% Two-colors
 \textcolor{blue!50!red}{I used two colors for this text}

  %% Three-colors

\textcolor{green!!red!!yellow}{It is the correct way to use three colors for this text}
    
%%or
\textcolor{green!40!red!20!yellow}{It is the correct way to use three colors for this text}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: See here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

Comment: Did you answer your own question?

Comment: Sir, I didn't answer my question. only I wrote the codes texts, that is correct or not?

Comment: I believe the comment was to indicate that your code example shows how it might be done.

Comment: Here is a helpful question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/shades-of-colors

Comment: Unless you mean to use multiple colors across the width of a text block, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307974/how-to-implement-automatic-line-breaking-in-gradient-colored-text?noredirect=1&lq=1